# Donut Tutorial: Stop sprinkles from intersecting

Tags: geometry-nodes, intersection

I started Blender guru's donut tutorial and it's brillant so far. But one thing **really** annoys me.

My sprinkles are intersecting at some points and in the tutorial he doesn't say how to fix it. It's not that big of a deal, since you can play with the seeds, but for a realistic amount of sprinkles there are always intersection, which bothers me.

I know that the solution for this problem might be difficult, but that's okay.

The (theoretical) solution in my head would be:

- find intersecting sprinkles
- choose one of them
- move it on the z-axis (so it now would look like it's floating)
- rotate it, so that it touches the icing and the other sprinkle
- correct the positioning (since the rotation will lead to another - smaller - intersection)

But since I'm a beginner I really don't know how do this in blender. I'd be able to mathematically solve the issue and maybe I could also code this. But in blender I have no clue.

**My icing geometry nodes so far**

[image]

Playing around with the poisson disk, the sprinkles density and the seed doesn't solve the problem of intersection in the way I'd like. I think it would look more realistic if there are some sprinkles on top of each other, because that happens if you use sprinkles

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The particles probably aren't the problem, as with the poisson disc that should all be separated.  The instances aren't as intelligent.  There may be a way to find out of the bounding box area of a sprinkle is inside the bounding box area of another and then, if so, remove it.  I don't know the maths for that, but it probably is doable.

Otherwise, I would do the sprinkles with dynamics.  Make a bunch of the sprinkles, make them active dynamic objects, the icing a passive collider with a lot of friction and drop them onto the surface. They will self-collide and then you can bake them out as objects after.  this will do what you really want them to get in Geometry Nodes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that helps a little bit! I don't know how to do this, but I guess that I could find it out, since this seems like a more common thing to do in blender than find intersections and rotate things.
But what's also strange: if I set the poisson disk distance to the size of the longest sprinkle (which should lead to no collision, but still much room for sprinkles) I can't get much sprinkles, no matter what I do. If I increase the sprinkle density, it doesn't really change the problem, that I only get a max of 10sprinkles, which is odd since there's room for like 100 not intersecting sprinkles